# Error ejecutando COM - CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE - C#

Tags: c#

Voy a empezar con el error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {1CF0DE77-8CAE-11D1-82A2-0060083F9B01} 
>   failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed 
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

A veces (no siempre), cuándo estoy ejecutando una función que me viene definida por un `COM` me sale ese error y no hay manera de solucionarlo.

He aplicado ya las "normas" en la definición de las COM:

- Tener `Interface`
- Asegurarse de tener definido en las clases:

  ```
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  [Guid("XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")] //GUID que se desee
  [ProgId("NombredeCom")]
  [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IInterfaceDefinida))]
  ```

Dónde el `GUID` está bien definido, la `IInterfaceDefinida` es `comvisible` y no da ningún error ni warning de compilación.

Pero, a veces, aparece el error que he mencionado sin motivo aparente. ¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si después de hacer todo lo que se indica en la pregunta sigue tirando ese error, el motivo es **muy sencillo**:

**Carga de CPU**

Después de investigar mucho he encontrado pequeñas perlas (aquí la [primera](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/06/24/when-cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-co_e_server_exec_failure/), la [segunda](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c47ebbf6-60fd-46f8-a41c-e8013919e528/cocreateinstance-returns-0x80080005-coeserverexecfailure-sometimes?forum=itproxpsp) y la [tercera](http://www.windowswally.com/how-to-fix-the-co_e_server_exec_failure-error/)) en la que se menciona de pasada el tema de la carga de la CPU.

Eso no es posible de arreglar directamente ya que no depende de la propia aplicación pero se puede capturar el error:

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.Contains("CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Carga de CPU muy alta. Inténtelo más tarde.");
        }
    }
```

Y a la vez buscar *por qué* hay una alta carga de CPU.